# How can I select an anonymous HTML element with text value?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-manipulation

You know these days we are using [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) or something like class and id concealer. But this time I have to select those elements with JS selectors. **But I can't handle that.**

I  got'an example here. You can see the **[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/)** home screen here. I wanna select the **"Subscription"** sidebar button. I think I have to use "Subscription" text value like `document.getElementByValue("Subscription")` What do you think about this. Does a kinda similar thing is existing?

How can I select using with JS selectors?

[image]

The source that I found while researching:

- https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/
- https://usefulangle.com/post/83/html-select-common-operations-with-javascript

Comment: `document.getElementByValue("Subscriptions")[0]` try this

Comment: @RayeesAC I tired but the consol log is ```Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByValue is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:10```

Comment: then try `getElementById("endpoint").value`

Comment: There is no such thing in js as "document.getElementByValue" and 'endpoint' id is not unique. Try to see my solution.

Comment: @RayeesAC Sory but your solutions are not working. But thanks for trying.

Comment: i added answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighted on screenshot element is not unique in the sence of classes.
You can for example select all elements with such classes and in a loop find which contains text Subscription.
Code below finds suraunding element and gets span inside of this.

```
document.querySelector("[aria-label='Subscriptions'] span")
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Smirnov that's work. But I have another question if I wanna select this element's upper element. How can I do that? I wanna select the whole subscription element

Comment: You mean ```yt-icon```? Just replace ```span``` in the answer with ```yt-icon```. What is this element's upper element in your case? Is it parent element or its sibling before it? If parent then ```document.querySelector(...).parentNode```. If sibling then i dont know.

Comment: This is definitely the solution's my question. Thank you bro I so appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead, you can find by **title** as **Subscriptions** near the **span**

```
var obj = document.querySelector("title='Subscriptions'] span.title");
console.log(obj.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys I solved my issue. Thank you so much for helping me @Alexander Smirnov.

You can use both of the selectors. I learn from that question `.parentNode` concept it's so helpful for me.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('style-scope ytd-mini-guide-renderer')[3]
```

or

```
document.querySelector("[aria-label='Subscriptions'] span").parentNode
```